# Flutter gradient rainbow outline and blur

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, gradient

I'm revisiting the flutter and want to build my small test application.
I'm opting for dark mode with nice gradient contrasts.

Would like to ask how I could achieve the rainbow outline with outside blur effect in Flutter.
Apple M1 logo has a great example of what I look for. Anyone could suggest how this can be done ??

[image]

Comment: you need `BackdropFilter` widget

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by `BoxShadow` inside `BoxDecoration` if you position the shadow well because you can put as many shadows as you can.

I just give a simple example how to do with it with 4 colors:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            offset: Offset(-20, 20),
            color: Colors.red,
            blurRadius: 15,
            spreadRadius: -10,
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            offset: Offset(-20, -20),
            color: Colors.orange,
            blurRadius: 15,
            spreadRadius: -10,
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            offset: Offset(20, -20),
            color: Colors.blue,
            blurRadius: 15,
            spreadRadius: -10,
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            offset: Offset(20, 20),
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
            blurRadius: 15,
            spreadRadius: -10,
          )
        ]),
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Center(
              child: Text(
            'Text',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40),
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The output should look like this:

[image]